# Constructors in a Spring Data JPA Entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I want an Entity Test with a map of question and answers (multiple answers allowed for one question). This is the tables (fixed) :

```
_____________
|Question   |
|-----------|
|+ id       |
|+ question |
|___________|

_____________
|Answer     |
|-----------|
|+ id       |
|+ answer   |
|___________|

_____________
|wrong      |   -- ASSOCIATION WITH TRICKY ANSWERS
|-----------|
|+ answer   |
|+ question |
|___________|

_____________
|exact      |   -- ASSOCIATION WITH CORRECT ANSWERS
|-----------|
|+ answer   |
|+ question |
|___________|

_____________
|Test       |
|-----------|
|+ id       |
|___________|

_____________
|Selection  |
|-----------|
|+ id       |
|+ test     |
|+ question |
|___________|

_____________
|reply      |
|-----------|
|+ selection|
|+ answer   |
|___________|
```

In my Entity Test, I want to put that lines but the code does not compile...

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "selection", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_test"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinTable(
                name = "reply", 
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_selection"), 
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_answer")))
private Map<Question, List<Answer>> selections;
```

I don't like to have an Entity Selection, it is very "ugly" and I don't find a solution on the web...

Comment: _inverseJoinColumns_ is utterly wrong and should be `@JoinColumn` array. And?

Comment: What is a @JoinColumn array ?

Comment: An array of `@JoinColumn` just like the ANNOTATION tells you. http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/annotations.html#JoinTable

Comment: I don't understand what it is...

Comment: Someone know how i can do that ?

Comment: Maybe I can link the table SELECTION with a secondary table. Then, I use a JoinColumn for link QUESTION and a JoinTable for link ANSWER. I try this solution, if it works, I post it here ! Wish me good luck !